# What does corner.ravel() does?

Tags: python, opencv

I couldn't understand the use of `corner.ravel()` in a source code regarding corner detection.

Here is the corresponding source code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread('simple.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

corners = cv2.goodFeaturesToTrack(gray,25,0.01,10)
corners = np.int0(corners)

for corner in corners:
    x,y = corner.ravel()
    cv2.circle(img,(x,y),3,255,-1)

plt.imshow(img),plt.show()
```

If someone can explain, it will be great help.
Thank You!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`.ravel()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html), is an attribute to numpy matrices, which can be used to faltten the src Matrix, there are other similar APIs' as well which can be used for this purpose such as : `.flatten()`, `.reshape()`

Comment: what would the javascript equivalent be?